# Simplification possible in example using print! and flush?

Tags: input, rust, output, flush

I started programming Rust a couple of days ago by working through the official documentation. Now I'm trying to challenge my understanding of Rust by working through the book "Exercises for Programmers" by Brian P. Hogan (The Pragmatic Programmers).

The first exercise is to write a program that asks the user for a name and prints out a greeting using that name. Input, string concatenation and output should be done in three distinct steps.

```
What is your name? Patrick
Hello, Patrick, nice to meet you.
```

The name will be entered at the same line as the initial prompt. Here's my solution:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    print!("What is your name? ");
    match io::stdout().flush() {
        Ok(_) => print!(""),
        Err(error) => println!("{}", error),
    }
    let mut name = String::new();
    match io::stdin().read_line(&mut name) {
        Ok(_) => {
            name = name.trim().to_string();
            if name.len() > 0 {
                let greeting = "Hello, ".to_string() + &name + &", nice to meet you!".to_string();
                println!("{}", greeting);
            } else {
                println!("No name entered, goodbye.");
            }
        }
        Err(error) => println!("{}", error),
    }
}
```

The `print!` macro doesn't actually output the prompt until I call `flush`. `flush` needs error handling, so I need both to handle the `Ok` and the `Err` case. In case of `Ok`, there's nothing useful to do, so I just `print!` an empty string.

Is there a shorter way to handle this? Maybe the error handling can be skipped or simplified somehow, or the whole `print!`/`flush` approach is the wrong one. (Everything works fine, but I could write this shorter in C, after all...)

Comment: Why not just call unwrap, like so: `io::stdout().flush().unwrap()`? With something like flush, which should almost never fail, that should be sufficient.

Comment: Well, thanks! That works. I just don't understand yet, why. I worked through "the book" to chapter 4.12, but unwrap() is only handled in chapter [5.7 (error handling)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html).

Comment: I'd recommend reading that error handling section. It goes over all the details of what unwrap does, as well as other options for simplifying error handling.

Comment: OK. Rust seems to be a hard nut to crack. Even an advanced hello world example needs intimate knowledge of the error handling mechanism ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As other people have said, make sure to read the [error handling chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html).

In most cases, you don't want to use `println!` to report errors. Either you should return the error from your function and let the caller deal with it, or you should use `panic!` to abort that thread and potentially the process.

```
match io::stdout().flush() {
    Ok(_) => print!(""),
    Err(error) => println!("{}", error),
}
```

Instead of printing nothing (which is inefficient), you can just... do nothing:

```
match io::stdout().flush() {
    Ok(_) => (),
    Err(error) => println!("{}", error),
}
```

Since you don't care about the success case, you can use an `if let`:

```
if let Err(error) = io::stdout().flush() {
    println!("{}", error);
}
```

Replacing the `println` with a `panic!` would be even better:

```
if let Err(error) = io::stdout().flush() {
    panic!("{}", error);
}
```

This is almost exactly what [`Option::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) does ([source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.34.1/src/libcore/option.rs#L342-L347)), except it also returns the successful value when present:

```
pub fn unwrap(self) -> T {
    match self {
        Some(val) => val,
        None => panic!("called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value"),
    }
}
```

However, it's **even better** to use [`Option::expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.expect) which allows you to specify an additional error message:

```
io::stdout().flush().expect("Unable to flush stdout");
```

Applying that twice:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    print!("What is your name? ");

    io::stdout().flush().expect("Unable to flush stdout");

    let mut name = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut name)
        .expect("Unable to read the line");

    let name = name.trim();

    if !name.is_empty() {
        println!("Hello, {}, nice to meet you!", name);
    } else {
        println!("No name entered, goodbye.");
    }
}
```

Note that there's no need to re-allocate a `String`, you can just shadow `name`, and there's no need to use `format` just to print out stuff.

Since Rust 1.26.0, you could also choose to return a `Result` from `main`:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    print!("What is your name? ");
    io::stdout().flush()?;

    let mut name = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut name)?;

    let name = name.trim();

    if !name.is_empty() {
        println!("Hello, {}, nice to meet you!", name);
    } else {
        println!("No name entered, goodbye.");
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

> but I could write this shorter in C, after all...

I would encourage / challenge you to attempt this. Note that every memory allocation in this program is checked, as is every failure case dealing with the standard output. Many people are not aware that C's `printf` **returns an error code** that you should be checking. Try outputting to a pipe that has been closed for an example.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out all the different options. The empty block probably was what I am was looking for initially (instead of printing an empty String). But the other options are even better.
I really need to work through the whole intro "book" first, before I tackle exercises. Rust has a steep learning curve.
Talking about the C example: that might be shorter by using an upper limit for the length of name. And the concatenation must be a distinct step for that exercise, otherwise it would be shorter, of course.